# Linux bridge won't forward IP packets from a vintage BSD machine --- but packets from other Linuxes are fine

Tags: linux, networking, ethernet, bridge, tap

#### Overview

I'm using a Linux single-board computer as an Ethernet bridge between an AWS host and [a very old and very rare Unix computer](http://www.cpu-ns32k.net/Whitechapel.html). This setup, which was working until a recent `sudo apt upgrade` on the single-board machine broke something, is diagrammed [in this image](http://www.cpu-ns32k.net/images/White_8.png). **The bridge now appears not to pass some Ethernet frames from the old Unix box, but *will* do it for Ethernet frames from a modern Linux computer!** I'm wondering what changed and how I can fix it.

#### Setup

In case the diagram linked above is inaccessible, here is a schematic:

```
                     +----------------------------+            +----------------+
                     |  Raspberry Pi              |            |  AWS host      |
                     |                +--------+  |            | +---------+    |
+---------+          |                | fastd   \....internet.....\  fastd |    |
| Vintage |--10bT--[eth0]===[br0]===[lance0]    / |            |  /   [lance0]  |
| BSD 4.2 |          |                +--------+  |            | +---------+    |
+---------+          |                            |            |                |
                     +----------------------------+            +----------------+
```

In this setup, instances of [fastd](https://fastd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) (in TAP mode) on the Pi and on the AWS host act as a virtual Ethernet cable between those two machines. I've tested that it works by using [etherp](https://github.com/albinou/etherp) to send raw Ethernet frames across the link in both directions, from Pi to AWS and vice versa. Since you need a name for an Ethernet interface, I've used `lance0` as [an historical homage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMD_Lance_Am7990).

Now, over on the Pi, I would like to plug my virtual Ethernet cable, as well as the very real Ethernet interface `eth0`, into a virtual Ethernet hub, and that's what `br0` is for. It's your standard TAP bridge, established via

```
ip link add name br0 type bridge
ip link set dev br0 up

ip link set dev lance0 master br0
ip link set dev eth0 master br0
```

Once I've done that, it should be as if I've plugged the old BSD box and the `[lance0].......[lance0]` "Ethernet cable" into the same Ethernet hub. BSD and AWS should be able to talk to each other over this two-computer Ethernet network.

#### The problem

Imagine that I'm logged into the AWS host. I have an IP (v4, of course) assigned to `lance0`. I would like to ping my vintage BSD box. To simplify things, I've set up the ARP tables manually on the BSD machine (which has its own IP) and on the AWS host --- this means that the *only* traffic will be ICMP packets (the computers can skip the ARP exchange). The pings don't go through, so to investigate we inspect things on the Pi with `tcpdump -i [interface]`. We observe:

- On `eth0` it looks good. You see echo requests from the AWS box and echo replies from the BSD box.
- On `br0` it's the same story: looks good.
- On `lance0`, though, you only see the echo requests. The echo replies are being dropped!

Now suppose you substitute a modern Linux machine on the end of the `eth0` cable in the place of the 36-year-old BSD box. Surprise: pings go through, everything works fine!

#### Observations

**Ethernet and TCP/IP work fine on the vintage BSD machine.** You can get rid of all the bridging and just hang an IP on the Pi's `eth0` and ping/telnet/ftp the BSD box from the Pi all day long.

**The ICMP packets between BSD and Linux seem identical.** Using `tcpdump -i br0 -XX` on the bridge, I examined hexdumps of the ping packets with their link layer headers. I can't see any reason why it would like pings from the modern Linux box but not the old BSD box. You can make a comparison yourself by viewing [this paste](https://pastebin.com/JKZAfD9T) (here's a [backup](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1x-1gomAnVWvRe1AEgxOvYILGu5W_pnfogEuIUFLMuUQ/edit?usp=sharing)).

**The fastd link is probably not the problem.** As noted above --- otherwise pings between the AWS box and the modern Linux machine wouldn't work at all.

**The "usual suspects" don't seem to be responsible.** [This page](http://www.microhowto.info/troubleshooting/troubleshooting_ethernet_bridging_on_linux.html) and a lot of StackOverflow/ServerFault pages have good suggestions that don't seem to apply here. On the Pi, `brctl show` looks normal; `brctl showstp br0` shows that `eth0` and `lance0` are in forwarding mode; and `brctl showmacs br0` shows the correct Ethernet addresses for everyone involved. The `ebtables` tables "filter" and "nat" are all empty with ACCEPT policies. The `arptables` table "filter" is the same way. Running `iptables-save` gives you nothing (there are no entries).

**The bridge WILL pass Ethernet broadcast frames!** Occasionally the old NTP daemon on the BSD box sends out broadcast UDP messages, which get packed into Ethernet broadcast frames addressed to ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff. These frames *do* make it to the AWS host, even though frames to non-broadcast addresses *don't* seem to make it.

**All of this was working a couple of months ago.** It only broke in early February, I think.

#### The question

So, why does Ethernet tap bridging by Linux on the Pi not want to pass some (non-broadcast) vintage Ethernet frames with IP payloads anymore? If nobody knows, are there any other tools I can use to try and identify a difference between these frames?

Comment: And what happened *early February*? Linux host upgrade?

Comment: I think so. I suspect it was a routine `sudo apt update; sudo apt upgrade` on the Pi, though I wasn't keeping track of precisely what got updated then, unfortunately.

I'd also been updating the AWS host routinely, but as the setup there is less complicated, I'm not so suspicious of it. Can't rule it out, though.

Comment: apt has logs, maybe something important was updated.

Comment: I would try to remove ebtables ad check sysctl, I would try to reset all "security"/filtering in sysctl. Also in this setup, there's no need for STP, IMO.

Comment: Scanning over the logs, many things are present but nothing looks too promising. fastd was updated in December to address some security issues, but the patches seem unrelated. I'm most suspicious of a kernel update (of which there have been several). That said, I tried reverting to earlier kernels via `rpi-update`, and that seemed not to help. (Maybe a change snuck in via base-files?) `brctl show` shows that stp is disabled. ebtables are empty, but I'll try uninstalling it altogether. As for security settings, there are many options --- do you have suggestions for a range of things to try?